# C# FileSystemWatcher & StreamReader gives "File is being used by another process" error

Tags: streamreader, filesystemwatcher

I have codes to watch a folder and open to read new files. When new file(s) fall into folder program works and do what it should do. Problem is related with other next file(s). If another file(s) fall into folder, program is giving "File is being used by another process" error message. I already read every similar questions in Stackoverflow and in Google. But non of them solved my problem. I don't think that problem is with my codes since when I assign same codes to a button and click manually after file falls to folder, program is working properly. But when FileSystemWatcher runs those codes it gives error at second time. Is there anyone who can advise a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the reason of the problem but I found my own solution.
I gave-up using FileSystemWatcher, instead I created a timer for 1 minute and at the end I check file quantity in the folder. If there is any change, I run the main codes. Now my problem has been fixed.